# Why i can not refer object properties when that object is passed as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a reusable components and use props to style every element inside it , i have created an object as **classes prop**
which contain fields represents classes of all elements in the component.

I need to use this object to style the component but referring object fields throw an error: `classes.prop is not defined`

**code**:

```
const Price = ({classes, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <div >
            <s className={classes.originalPriceClasses}> //not defined
                {props.originalPrice}
            </s>&nbsp;
            <span className={classes.newpriceClasses}> //not defined
                {props.newPrice}
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
<Price 
  classes={{
    originalPriceClasses: "text-primary",
    newPriceClasses: "font-size-bg"
  }}
/>
```

**Update:**

The problem occur when passing **Price** component as a value to a prop like doing this:

```
<Card 
   text= {
    <Price 
      classes={{
        originalPriceClasses: "text-primary",
        newPriceClasses: "font-size-bg"
      }}
    />

   }
>
```

but when i passed **Price** as a child using **props.children**it worked:

```
 <Card >
  <Price 
     classes={{
        originalPriceClasses: "text-primary",
        newPriceClasses: "font-size-bg"
      }}
  />
</Card>
```

Why referring classes properties in the first scenario returns a reference error??

Comment: `originalPriceClasses` comes through fine for me. `newpriceClasses` is a typo in your code. It should be `newPriceClasses`. Is there more to this code that might determine the classes on `<Price />`? Maybe those are dynamic? Check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-dawn-nqlzu

Comment: so in theory this should work, but unfortunately it does not work in my project

Comment: Could you create a sandbox with your code? Codesandbox is a nice one.

Comment: this would be difficult because the consuming component is complex and consume many other components but when i tried the demo in codesandbox it worked this means there is something wrong that is unexpected

Comment: I don't think the code that's causing this error is included in the question. @SaherElgendy, is it possible you're calling `classes.prop` somewhere else?

Comment: Guys, i think i found the origin of the problem, i have two scenarios of calling Price component with the classes prop, one of them was to pass the whole component as a value to  a prop and here i could not refer to object properties and get that reference error, and the second when i used children.props and that made it work, i updated the code to show when the problem is manifested

Comment: i do not know why the first scenario cause the problem!! do you have any explanation please